# 403 Forbidden response from Alexa while using Progressive Response

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am using Alexa.NET to implement an Alexa skill, when I try to send a progressive response from my handler

```
var progressiveResponse = new ProgressiveResponse(information.SkillRequest);
await progressiveResponse.SendSpeech("please wait");
```

I receive a 403 response result. I suspect that the Access Token does not provide some permission required to use this API but I am confused, I do not see any related permission in the skill page. Everything apart this works correctly.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

In general, Progressive Responses do not change the overall time allowed for a response. When a user invokes a skill, the skill has approximately 8 seconds to return a full response. The skill must finish processing any progressive responses as well as the full response within this time. You can send progressive responses from the context of a current LaunchRequest or IntentRequest; however, you cannot send progressive responses from any other request types (such as AudioPlayer requests).

The 403 error is also returned if the requestId represents a request that is no longer applicable, such as when the progressive response is received after skill's full response.

Additionally, you may want to check below to ensure you are able to properly obtain Required Data for the Progressive Response API
https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/custom-skills/send-the-user-a-progressive-response.html#required-data

If after checking the suggestions above you are still running into trouble, you can reach reach out to the Alexa Developer Support via this link: https://developer.amazon.com/alexa/console/contact-us